# Weird MySQL Errors After Distrib Upgrade (SQL 5.0 > 5.1)

Tags: mysql, debian-squeeze, mysql5, myisam

Just updated Debian from Lenny to Squeeze on one of my servers. It hosts a MySQL server. Upgrade went fine, but afterwords, when MySQL starts up, it checks the databases to make sure they are okay. I am getting errors though for tables that are in the mysql database.

I did an extensive Google search and attempted to do a myiasmchk -r to those tables. Outside of that, I have not found any other possible answers.

Is this just a bug? Is there a way to fix it?

> ERROR 1034 (HY000) at line 1: Incorrect key file for table 'columns_priv'; try to repair it
>
> ERROR 1034 (HY000) at line 1: Incorrect key file for table 'db'; try to repair it
>
> ERROR 1034 (HY000) at line 1: Incorrect key file for table 'func'; try to repair it
>
> ERROR 1034 (HY000) at line 1: Incorrect key file for table 'host'; try to repair it
>
> ERROR 1034 (HY000) at line 1: Incorrect key file for table 'tables_priv'; try to repair it

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed as bug, patch and details [here](http://lists.mysql.com/commits/73145)

Answer (score 0):

connect to mysql server and do a commands

repair table func;
repair table db;
repair table host;

etc...

Comment: Gave that a shot but unfortunately it did not resolve the problem.